# Wordpress Domain And Hosting issue

Tags: wordpress, dns, web-hosting

Good Noon, I am stuck in a problem that I am the old owner of the domain named goldaccesshk.com and this domain is expired and bought by some other company and I have removed all the data from my Hosting all files including my database but unfortunately when ever I hit the goldaccesshk.com url it is still showing me the results . How can I resolve that issue . A screenshot is mentioned below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oup4i.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is surely the cache system of your browser because I have nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Check your wordpress hosting server. The hosting server will cache the files and serve for sometimes. So clear the cache on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Remember we have two part:

#1. Domain registration
#2. Hosting provider

You lose the #1 and still with #2, so if the site still working maybe:

#1. Your cache (this apply if only you be access)
#2. The new domain owner not changed the DNS server on domain registra company.

I believe your problem is the #2, so to solve this you can change the domain on your hosting provider because curenctly he is configured to answer to this domain (You can just change the domain to anything).